# Entity Framework Cascade Delete on multiple conditions

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

There is this entity:

```
public class Basket
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Apple")]
    public int AppleId { get; set; }
    public Apple Apple { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Banana")]
    public int BananaId { get; set; }
    public Banana Banana { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Cherry")]
    public int CherryId { get; set; }
    public Cherry Cherry { get; set; }           
}
```

I have named them like this just to give a concrete example.

In "basket" table, i will have 4 different columns and 3 of them will be the IDs of "apple","banana" and "cherry". I would like to set a **CASCADE DELETE** condition, if one those 3 will be deleted, so must the rows contain that ID.

So far I couldn't get it done since "apple","banana" and "cherry" won't contain the ID of "basket".

Thank you.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. The "one" end of a one-to-many relationship doesn't need to - and by definition, cannot - contain the primary key of the "many" end of the relationship in order to enable cascade delete.

Comment: in this case, the "one" end should be one of the three. "basket" is the many end. and none of those 3 contain the primary key of the "many" end aka "basket"

Comment: That's just three standard one-to-many relationships. The "one" end cannot contain the IDs from the "many" end.

Answer (score 0):

You're describing an entity which is the "many" end of three standard one-to-many relationships.

In EF Core's fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Basket>()
    .HasOne(b => b.Apple).WithMany().HasForeignKey(b => b.AppleId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

modelBuilder.Entity<Basket>()
    .HasOne(b => b.Banana).WithMany().HasForeignKey(b => b.BananaId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

modelBuilder.Entity<Basket>()
    .HasOne(b => b.Cherry).WithMany().HasForeignKey(b => b.CherryId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

[Cascade Delete - EF Core | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete)